# How to maintain "Ignore/handle subsequent exceptions" breakpoints between developers?

Tags: delphi, debugging, svn, breakpoints

Sometimes there are pieces of code where exceptions occur that you don't want to stop execution in the IDE (e.g. OLE exceptions when setting up a connection).

The trick is to place 2 breakpoints around this, with the 1st set to "Ignore subsequent exceptions" and the 2nd to "Handle subsequent exceptions".

This works fine when you are the only one working on the code, the breakpoint moves with the code.

However, when several developers update the same file and you import/export from/to version control (SVN in my case) the breakpoints can end up on the wrong lines and you have to reset them.

This is because these breakpoint settings are maintained locally in the IDE configuration.

*Has anyone ever found a way to maintain these breakpoints among developers? How?*

Using Delphi XE2 for W32 apps.

Comment: Oh great! This solves my long standing bug bear that FastMM full debug throws AVs that can be ignored. Now I can ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

These breakpoints are stored in a DSK file - either that of the project or that of the project group, depending on what was open in the IDE. You may consider adding those files to the version control. However, this might have other significant drawbacks.